# How to average data based on combination of other data?

Tags: ms-access

I have a set of data with multiple rows and it looks something like this:

```
Datere      Profile    P_code   Proctime
----------------------------------------
28/02/19    DIE        B6850    5
28/02/19    DIE        C6851    7
28/02/19    DIE        M0211    9
01/03/19    DIE        H9923    5
01/03/19    DIE        C8850    6
01/03/19    DIFT       OP821    9
```

I want to average the `Proctime` based on the combination of `Datere` and `Profile`. The `P_code` column is not needed.

The result should look something like this:

```
Datere      Profile    Proctime
--------------------------------
28/02/19    DIE        7
01/03/19    DIE        5,5
01/03/19    DIFT       9
```

Is there any way to fix this? Much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you can just use a query like so:

```
select Datere, Profile, Avg(Proctime) as AvgProc
from YourTableName
Group by Datere, Profile
```

Just know that Access Query Builder also has a SQL view that you could use to type this query.

Comment: I have tried it but "Your query does not include the specified expression as 'Datere' as part of an aggregate function." box comes out. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Can you copy and paste my query? I did not have a group by clause when I posted the answer initially.